# every element is 1x1 matrix in python, How do i make it so that every element is not seperate?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

print(s0[3][0][0]) gives me 1

but print(s0[3][0]) gives me [1]

how do i make it so that print(s0[3][0]) gives me 1?

S0 is a numpy matrix of 100 rows

```
S0 = 
[[[ 1.        ]
  [-0.91903376]
  [ 0.18724527]]

 [[ 1.        ]
  [ 0.87834638]
  [-0.88794145]]

 [[ 1.        ]
  [-0.75320818]
  [ 0.59000726]]]
```

small sample ^

Comment: You have a 3 dimensional matrix, do you want a 2 dimensional one? Remove the inner brackets and insert commas between numbers, i.e. `S0 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`.

Comment: `s0[3,0,0]` selects an element from a 3d array.  Looks like you have a (3,3,1) shaped array.  Have you read about `shape` and `reshape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some time to read `numpy` basics.  The key here is `shape`.  You have a 3d array:

```
In [122]: arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3,1)
In [123]: arr
Out[123]: 
array([[[0],
        [1],
        [2]],

       [[3],
        [4],
        [5]],

       [[6],
        [7],
        [8]]])
In [124]: arr.shape
Out[124]: (3, 3, 1)
```

You can index such an array with

```
In [125]: arr[:,:,0]
Out[125]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [126]: _.shape
Out[126]: (3, 3)
```

`arr[0][0][0]` works, but `arr[0,0,0]` is clearer.

You can also get a 2d array from this with `reshape` (note that I used `reshape` to create the original array from the 1d `arange` array.

```
In [127]: arr.reshape(3,3)
Out[127]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

The display (and input) with all the [] and commas is nice for viewing arrays, but the sooner you become familiar with `shape` (and `reshape`) your `numpy` coding will be easier.

Comment: thank you for the advice! ill look into the basics

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the array S0 is a 3-d array. To get one value from this 3-d array you need to have three indices. In order to get value using two indices (S0[i][j]) you have to convert this to a 2-d array.

eg-

```
S1 =[[1.0, -0.91903376, 0.18724527],
[1.0, 0.87834638, -0.88794145],
[1.0, -0.75320818, 0.59000726]]
```

S1[0][0] now will give 1.0